# Is it possible to publish game update to AppStore and Google Play simulanously exactly at the same time?

Tags: google-play, app-store, google-play-services, versioning, publish

When developing online game I would really like to avoid supporting different protocol versions. The server can check the version of a client and deny login until the client gets updated. But the problem here is that I need the app update to become available simultanously at the same time on AppStore and Google Play.

Is it possible to do? How do you solve such versioning problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure how it works for the GooglePlayStore but if you choose *Developer Release* instead of automatic then you could just release it in the moment it approves on the GooglePlayStore and about 30mins. later your iOS app will be online and available as well. That's what I'd do.

Comment: Do you mean 1. submit developer release to appstore 2. wait for approval 3. submit to google play 4. wait for publish on google play 5. make developer release on appstore public ?

Comment: This is what I meant, yes. Not a so elegant solution but I guess it will work with few time discrepancy.